# Redraw AmStockChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, amcharts

I have several AmStockCharts on the page. Those are line graphs. The data gets fetched from MySQL DB in JSON format. If user clicks on a graph dot (a bullet) then a form gets showed up where user can modify the data and save it. In this case I would need to redraw the chart and I can't figure this out.

Here is the piece of code:

```
//drawing all charts there are
var chart;
$.getJSON('stats.php', function (data) { // get all data from all stats at once
    var i=0;
    for (chartData in data) {
        i++;
        chart = new AmCharts.AmStockChart();
        var dataSet = new AmChart.DataSet();
        dataSet.dataProvider = chartData;
        // etc. etc. here are all the single graph parameters
        $('#stats').append('<div id="chartdiv' + i + '"></div>');
        chart.write("chartdiv" + i);
    }
});
```

I get all charts drawn fine. But here are two problems then. First problem that I can't access them later as the 'chart' variable refers only to the last chart drawn. The second problem is that even if I try to redraw this last chart I get no result.

To redraw the chart I have tried the following:

```
function chart_redraw(stat) {
    $.getJSON('stat.php?redraw=' + stat, function (data) { // get data for one particular stat
    var dataSet = new AmCharts.DataSet();
    dataSet.dataProvider = data;
    ...
    chart.dataSets = [dataSet];

    var stockPanel = new AmChart.StockPanel();
    stockPanel.validateData();
    chart.panels = [stockPanel];

    chart.validateNow();
});
```

That didn't do anything, i.e. the chart does not get re-drawn.

The only thing I could do is to store the chart div in a hidden input at click event by:

```
function chartClick (event) {
    var chartdiv = event.event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id
    $('#chart_n').val(chartdiv);
    ...
}
```

and then use it to remove the chart from that div and crate new one at that place but it is much slower then the validateData() would be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When data is changed, all you need to do is set new data for data set:

```
dataSet.dataProvider = yourDataArray;
```

and then call

```
stockChart.validateData();
```

However your code should also change panel/dataset, so It's a bit strange for me. Do you get any console errors? In case not, I'd need to see full working source of your case., but I hipe my suggestion will work.

Comment: Ok, I couldn't make the whole thing but I made a simple code with two data sources which supposedly change at the a buttion click, evetually the graph should re-draw but it doesn't. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/33SDv/2/

Comment: You should also set chart.mainDataSet = dataSet; as it remembers previous data set and uses it.